# When does CSS's !important declaration not work?

Tags: css

I am wondering if someone can put a bit of an authoritative reference summary of when the !important declaration in CSS does **not** work to override inline styles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many factors involved in determining which styles override one another.  The lower a style declaration appears in the **cascade**, and the **more specific** it is in targeting the element, the more it will weigh against other styles.

This is the [CSS2 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) for style inheritance:

> 1. If the cascade results in a value, use it.
> 2. Otherwise, if the property is inherited, use the value of the parent
>      element, generally the computed value.
> 3. Otherwise use the property's initial value. The initial value of
>      each property is indicated in the
>      property's definition.

Internally, the browser will [calculate the specificity of a rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), according to the standard.  The !important declaration will add weight to the rule, but dynamically assigning a style attribute will often take precedence, because it is usually more-highly specified..

Comment: Well a dynamically assigned style attribute *is* getting overridden by !important in IE7, IE6 and FF2 at the moment which is why I'm curious (it's desired to be this way, just curious :-) )

Comment: I have style="display:none;" versus div#id div { display: block !important; }.  The latter wins. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules may be of some interest.

Comment: That's the correct behavior.. the descendant selector plus the !important declaration is most specific.

Comment: cool, I just wanted to clear up that dynamically assigning a style attribute will often take precedence as per your edit, not always. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 12):

Well so far research seems to suggest:

- IE7 supports !important.
- FireFox 2 and 3 support !important.
- IE6 supports !important in standards compliant mode.

However, IE6 (possible IE7) does not support !important in [this case](http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2005/06/16/essentials-of-css-hacking-for-internet-explorer/#comment-655):

```
someselector {
  property: value !important;
  same-property: another-value;
}
```

It will use the second value (the last listed).

This is confirmed by [this page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/importantdeclarations):

> In Internet Explorer 6 and earlier, if
>   an important declaration appears
>   before a normal declaration for the
>   same property within the same
>   declaration block, the normal
>   declaration will overwrite the
>   important declaration.
>
> Internet Explorer 6 and 7 give
>   importance to a declaration when an
>   illegal identifier is used in place of
>   the keyword important, instead of
>   ignoring the declaration as they
>   should.

Gizmo's comment states that Safari and Opera support !important.

Comment: it's actually an easy way to get IE only styles. #myBox { width: 300px !important; width: 290px } ... just make sure you comment it, so that next guy is left scratching his head!

Comment: Safari and Opera support it very well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure not all browsers recognise the !important declaration. But can't remember which ones do off the top of my head. Will check and get back to you.

[EDIT]
I can confirm IE6 and earlier do not recognise !important (unless the browser is in standards compliance mode - not the default).

You can use !important to override an inline rule. But also remember that inline rules can be tagged !important as well.

Comment: Heh, I have IE6 running in standards compliant mode and it is listening to the !important declaration.  Good point on inline style !important.

Comment: As Graphain says, IE6 can support !important.

Answer (score 1):

No answer has mentioned that `!important` will invalidate any properties that do not interact with the cascade ([see the W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/#keyframes)). For example, consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="bad-div" style="margin-left: 5px"></div>
```

which is styled by the following CSS:

```
#bad-div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: marginLeftInvalid 4s infinite ease-in 1s
}

@keyframes marginLeftInvalid {
    0% {
        margin-left: 100px!important
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: 500px
    }
}
```

Since `@keyframes` rules does not interact with the cascade, the `margin-left` style of the `<div>` will not be overwritten by the value inside the `0%` [<keyframe-selector>](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/#typedef-keyframe-selector).

However, when the HTML and CSS are updated to this:

```
<div id="good-div" style="margin-left: 5px"></div>

#good-div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: marginLeftValid 4s infinite ease-in 1s
}

@keyframes marginLeftValid {
    0% {
        margin-left: 100px
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: 500px
    }
}
```

the `margin-left` at `0%` *is* enforced, and the animation will continue to cycle with a starting `margin-left` of 100px.

You can see a demonstration within [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/okfsygLv/).

Other at-rules which do not cascade (and therefore `!important` will invalidates properties properties within these declarations) include:

1. @font-face
2. @viewport
3. @counter-style
4. @property
5. @page
6. @color-profile
7. @scroll-timeline

A demonstration of `@font-face` and its lack of participation in the the cascade can be seen using [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/vaibhav_neo/pen/WNNqRyX). Make these CSS updates:

1. Add the attribute `style="font-family: moderna"` for the first `h1` tag in the DOM; delete this same rule from the `h1` within the CSS.
2. Add `!important` after the first `'moderna'` you see in the CSS (`font-family` descriptor within the first `@font-face`) - the font rendering of the heading will break.
3. Reload the page and repeat #2 for the 2nd `src` descriptor (add after `format()`) ... font rendering for the `h1` breaks.
4. Revert this, and then to the first `h1 {...}` declaration in the CSS, add the style ---> `font-family: 'arsenalregular'` ... you'll notice 'moderna' is NOT overwritten.
5. Revert this, and then add `!important` after the first `'arsenalregular'` you see (`font-family` descriptor within the second `@font-face`) - the font rendering of the heading will not change.
6. reload the page and find `'moderna'` within the first `h1` declaration - add `!important` after `'moderna'` - the font rendering of the `h1` DOES render as `arsenalregular` because - in the CSS - this `h1 {...}` declaration *is* part of the cascade.

A demonstration of the non-participation of `@counter-style` in the CSS cascade can be seen (in Firefox) on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/4r3k0tex/). Notice that the list glyph rendering breaks when `!important` is appended to the declaration value of the `symbols` descriptor, whereas the list glyph `suffix` rendering breaks when `!important` is appended to the `suffix` descriptor.

NOTE: other at-rules DO cascade. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/6trxmpyg/) which shows `!important` being applied within `@supports` and `@layer`. As of February 2022, due to lack of support for `@layer` ([0.02%](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40layer)) please use Firefox 97 or greater for this JSFiddle.