# How can I override the CSS style IN a table

Tags: html, css, tinymce, html-table

When you stretch  your table in tinymce you get this

```
<table class="opbouw" style="width: 725px; height: 170px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

However, I want it to be overridden because all tables must be 100% width for printing, else its looks crappy.

Can anyone tell me how to override it so the table is 100% when printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `width` is set inline with the `style` attribute you won't be able to override it. [Sometimes not even !Important will override it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189621/when-does-csss-important-declaration-not-work) If you can move the sizing information to a class, then you can reset the width to 100% in your print styles sheet.

If you do not want to add the size info to the class `opbouw`, then you can create a second class, for example, `narrowTable` and apply both to the table like this:

```
<table class="opbouw narrowTable" ...>
```

In your print stylesheet you can reset the size properties:

```
<style type="text/css">
 @media print
 {
     TABLE, .narrowTable
     {
         width: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
     }
  }

  @media screen
  {

     .opbouw
     {
     }

     .narrowTable
     {
         width: 725px;
         height: 150px;
         border: none;
     }

     /* all your normal screen styles */
  }
</style>
```

For more on CSS Selector Specificty (who wins when multiple styles are pointed at the same element), [see this here](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html), my most favorite CSS article on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Apply an `!important` rule to the end of it.

In Your CSS File:

```
table {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```