# CSS - "style" property not overriding class

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV container that is a CSS class defined on the top level. That container also has a style that has a couple elements that should override the main class elements. As far as I understand, this is what it should be doing, but it seems to ignore everything I am putting in there.

```
/* In the CSS file. */
div.ItemContainer {
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:15px;
    width:80px;
    height:70px;
}
```

and In the HTML file:

```
<div class="ItemContainer" style="left:200px; top:150px;">
    Test text.
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? If not, any suggestions on how to get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: Based on the code you pasted there is no reason this should be happening. The only thing that could override styles in the style attribute would be !important styles. Use something like Firebug or Chrome inspector to see the CSS inheritance of any element.

Comment: Verify that the element in question is a div. I generally make class-level selectors tag-agnostic. That is, ".ItemContainer" instead of "div.ItemContainer".

Comment: I tried all the suggestions so far, and none of them help. What I've shown above is from a pretty tricky dynamic page with elements created via javascript, so I'm guessing something is going wrong there. Looking into that instead.

Comment: @Eli: Are you using JavaScript to style your site?

Comment: *“I tried all the suggestions so far”* So, what was your result with the CSS inspector? Is it possible to see that page (maybe extract the problem and upload somewhere), so we can check it ourself?

Comment: I had a look with an inspector and indeed it is assigning it the 0px values to top and left, so something somewhere is doing it. It's a complicated project though so it'll take some investigating. I even (just for now) copied all elements from the class and put them in the style attribute.

Comment: And yes Javascript is doing some styling work.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that I'm using iScroll, a specific script that moves stuff around via javascript, simulating a scrollbar for iPhones. As initialization it probably moves everything to the left, which definitely doesn't help...

Comment: @Eli: What is iScroll exactly? Can you provide a link with more information so that we can suggest an alternate way of doing what it does?

Comment: If you're trying to change a DIV that's manipulated by Iscroll, perhaps the best approach is to change it using Iscroll... Without any more code from your part, it's hard to help you out...

Comment: Here is iScroll: http://cubiq.org/iscroll

I won't be able to share more code, unfortunately, but I'm very thankful for all the help so far. If I come up with a solution I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be alright. Have a look at the markup language you are using (HTML/XTML...) to see if it has an error such as a unclosed quotes, missing tag or missing end tag. Another thing that could mess up your style is the use of JavaScript for styling. It is a **bad practice** to use JavaScript for styling! Have a close look at what you are doing with the use of JavaScript for styling.

---

### iScroll

Using iScroll seems to be the source of your problem. You might want to use a JavaScript library that does not mess with CSS. Also, you could try to modify the library or find a way to bypass what ever you are doing with the library.

You might find something useful in these links:

- [jQuery TOOLS](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/index.html)
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

Comment: IE7+ has full support for `!important`. IE 5 and 6 have partial support for it. In fact it is interpreted correctly but overwritten if another style declaration follows *later*. No matter what, the OP's code should work without a problem as the style attribute takes first precedence (without `!important` declarations).

Comment: @poke: !important was fixed in a later release of IE7. A lot of people still do not find it important to update or to buy a newer operating system. I prefer allowing a majority of people the capability of viewing a site with the same experience than to deny them access because of layout issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189621/when-does-csss-important-declaration-not-work for a good discussion on the subject

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes things don't cascade correctly in some browsers. Use the `!important` flag to override behaviour.

```
style="left: 200px !important; top: 150px !important"
```

Comment: @Alerty actually, it does. It has (or had) some *bugs* with respect to `!important`, but it has always recognized `!important` and none of the bugs are relevant here.

Comment: @hobbs: Certain versions of IE does not support it. ;)

Comment: @Alerty But not versions that anyone uses. Let me say it again. IE6 supports `!important`. *IE6 supports `!important`.* **IE6 supports `!important`.** Were you perhaps referring to the versions of IE that are *older than CSS2*? Because they're the only ones that don't support `!important`.

Comment: @hobbs: IE6 supports CSS2 in an incorrect way: http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

Comment: And yet... it supports `!important`.

Comment: @hobbs: It does not support it in a standard compliant way.

Comment: @Alerty I know that. However it does work 99% **and** none of the problems it has affect this question at all **and** I already explained its limitations and the fact that they don't matter to this question **before** you made your repeated incorrect posts.

Comment: @hobbs: Anyway `!important` is not the solution. `I tried all the suggestions so far, and none of them help. What I've shown above is from a pretty tricky dynamic page with elements created via javascript, so I'm guessing something is going wrong there. Looking into that instead. – Eli Jul 2 at 23:15`

Answer (score 1):

try !important

```
left:200px !important;
```

Comment: That may work, but it would be a workaround. The OP's code should work.

Comment: IE does not recognize the !important flag.

Comment: In fact, certain versions of IE does not support !important at all or in a standard compliant way.

Comment: @Alerty:  It looks like this page/app might be targeted at iPhones.  But IE does support `!important` (buggily)  See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/importantdeclarations , for example.  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189621/when-does-csss-important-declaration-not-work/189661#189661