# How to raise css rules priority for an html snippet

Tags: html, css

I wrote a HTML/CSS snippet that is included in some 3-rd party website.
But CSS rules of that website make my snippet look terrible. To keep the snippet's appearance I must use **!important** keyword, but it's horrible, I have to write this keyword for about 1000 times (besides such a code looks not very nice).
I can also use inline CSS instead of external .css file, but it's not a solution too.
So, how can I protect my css styles in some elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestion to use a `div` with a unique ID is good. However, there is a chance that other rules in the host page's style sheet use `!important`. Those rules would override yours, even if you use a unique ID.

Short of using an external document in an  `iframe` in the first place (which is not always possible), using `!important` is the only 100% safe way that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

Your snippet should be included inside an `iframe`.

It's the usual way these "widgets for 3rd party sites" work.

If you use an `iframe`, CSS from the parent document can't affect your "HTML/CSS snippet".

Comment: Is the CSS of the site using `!important` in stupid ways? If not, the answers suggesting to prepend an `id` should definitely work. For example, `#myWidget p { .. }` / `#myWidget a` would override CSS from the rest of the document (like stuff being set on `body`). Provided that you do `#myWidget { /* set sensible defaults like font, line-height to avoid inheriting from the cascade */ }`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try enclosing your snippet inside a DIV with a unique id.

Then on your CSS for that snippet's style, include the id selector of the DIV  for the items in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to make the selectors more specific in some way. For example,

```
LI { color: red; }

LI.class { color: blue; }

<li class="class">I will be blue</li>
```

but you're really at the mercy of the 'rest of the CSS' you don't have control over.

I think your best bet is to put ID's and unique classes on all yoru stuff and spec the heck out of it. This is not great either though becuase you might WANT some of the 'rest of the CSS' to apply.

Comment: If `!important` won't do it, I don't believe increasing selector specificity can.

Comment: Important might not be supported everywhere. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189621/when-does-csss-important-declaration-not-work

Comment: !important doesn't overwrite inline styles, but 3-rd party website cannot modify my html tags, so this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't go with the iframe method, you'll need to figure out what level of [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) the parent page declarations have and beat that with your style declarations, keeping in mind that they'll still apply if you don't clear them.  Otherwise, bring on the "!important"s!!!  You may want to look for a clear.css or something as well that does this for you, as many sites offer this.