# why in this code Height: auto and Height: 100% on same element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was reading the Bootsrap3 documentation. I found this piece of code for footer sticking to bottom of screen.

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important; /* line no 1 */
height: 100%;            /* line no 2 */
margin: 0 auto -60px;
padding: 0 0 60px;
}
footer {
height: 60px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

I did not understand why they defined height of wrap multiple times. As far my knowledge auto will calculate height based on its child element and ! important will force browser to use this style. Then in which case height: 100% will take effect.

I was working with this code to test few things. I wrote two fiddle one with `height: auto !important;` and other without this code. Here is my [JsFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/UaYfW/57/) and [JsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/UaYfW/58/)
those fiddle are self explanatory. i just did not understand why it is happening like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some older browsers like IE6, ignore the `!important` flag. Thus on IE6 the second `height`  will be obeyed. It's just a way of targeting older browsers.

Comment: would you mind looking at the fiddle and giving me explanation for the behavior with and without that part of code.

Comment: It's not quite as simple as IE6 ignores !important: http://stackoverflow.com/a/189661/557612

Comment: @steveax that's a very good point, this hack is a lot more nuanced than my simple explanation. the link provided is a good read.

Comment: @Shubendra you are likely testing in a modern browser. if you remove the line with `!important`, that is a big change because now the browser will use `height:100%` instead of `height:auto`; As to why `height:auto` and `height:100%` behave the way they do, thats a different topic.