# Overriding CSS from element.style created by server side JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a reference to a server side JS file that dynamically creates divs on my page. I am trying to override the css that is inline for the divs that are created but I have not been able to do so.

I have tried !important and the style that is created by the JS still trumps everything I do.

When i look at the style in the developer console of chrome it shows element.style as being the style that "won" over my style
I do not have access to edit the JS file on the server.

I place this in my page and it dynamically creates the divs and styles them.

```
<head>

<style>
#id
 {
    background-color: blue; !important; 
    display:block; !important;  
}
.class
 {
    background-color: blue; !important; 
}

</style>

</head>


<script src="http://xxx/xxx/xxxxx/xxxx.ashx?blank=xxxx" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `server side JS`? Please post relevant code here.

Comment: Please provide Fiddle  link...

Comment: What is an example of the div with inline style and the style rule you wrote?

Comment: So what *do* you have access to? Just CSS, or JavaScript as well? What sample representative HTML can you show us? Incidentally, what do you think we gain from being shown that `<script>` tag?

Comment: Try to edit the style with jQuery inside the `document.ready` function. Then the script should have already created the content.

Comment: you are using !important after semicolon(;). It should be before semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You can create  your own javascript to restyle the divs created by the server javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS !important tag does sound like your answer here but sometimes you need to ensure your CSS declaration is specific enough to the element, i.e.:

```
<div>
<a style="color:#F00;">A Link</a>
</div>
```

If I apply the below CSS the inline style or #F00 will still win:

```
div {color:#fff !important;}
```

But if I am specific with my CSS declaration i.e:

```
div a {color:#000 !important;} <--Notice the 'a' tag
```

Then my link will be #000. This does not matter if the link was loaded in with JavaScript or not.

See my JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zqpy0r6c/

More technical info can be found at
[When does CSS's !important declaration not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189621/when-does-csss-important-declaration-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS given in the `style` attribute on an element always wins over the stylesheets. The best option to override this CSS is to edit the style attribute using some JS:

```
<script>
    function clearInlineStyling(element){
        element.style= null;
    }

</script>
```

Next you have to watch the html for your script to add new elements, find them and remove their styling. I would suggest JQuery for this.